# render declaration for map in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-maps, react-wrapper

I try to add @googlemaps/react-wrapper in my project,
following this explaination : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/react-map
But at the first instruction i have this,

```
const render = (status: Status) => {
  return <h1>{status}</h1>;
};
```

and if i really understand it is TypeScript and my project page is in javascript,
how to do the same thing in javascript ?
hope that it's not a too much stupid question. thanks by advance

Comment: Just _remove the type_, `: Status`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's it's JavaScript conversion:

```
var render = function (status) {
    return { status: status } < /h1>;;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the type :status like purpose by @jonrsharpe